# Which one is the next country most likely to be partly or fully annexed by Russia?

Tags: russian-federation

After Ukraine and Georgia, Which one is the next country most likely to be partly or fully annexed by Russia?

Comment: Any country at any given point is under the threat of annexation by Russia or any other country. So the answer too your question is "all countries other than Russia". If you are asking which country is more likely to be the next target, you are asking necessarily for speculation as there is no factually basis for that type of answers. Do you want an answer without a link too back it up?

Comment: This question is completely speculative. We can not predict the future. That makes it a bad fit for this website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the book "The Next 100 Years", author George Friedman offered Poland as a candidate for inevitable Russian aggression.  This prediction was more about that fact that Russia would invade something, as opposed to exactly which country Russia would target and it was written before the annexing of Crimea therefore was met with lots of skepticism at the time.